# ValueError: Layer model expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors using generator

Tags: cnn, rnn, training, text, image

I am trying to fit a model using generator function and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Layer model expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>]
```

Following is the code:

```
    try:
  os.mkdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/iCap/models")
except:
  pass
for i in range(epochs):
    generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, tokenizer, max_length)
    model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch= steps, verbose=1)
    model.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/iCap/models/model_" + str(i) + ".h5")
```

And following is the data_generator function I use:

```
    def data_generator(descriptions, features, tokenizer, max_length):
    while 1:
        for key, description_list in descriptions.items():
            #retrieve photo features
            feature = features[key][0]
            input_image, input_sequence, output_word = create_sequences(tokenizer, max_length, description_list, feature)
            yield [[input_image, input_sequence], output_word]
```

Could any of you please help to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say anything without seeing the model.

Comment: excuse me did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `data_generator` function.

Do this:

```
def data_generator(descriptions, features, tokenizer, max_length):
while 1:
    for key, description_list in descriptions.items():
        #retrieve photo features
        feature = features[key][0]
        input_image, input_sequence, output_word = create_sequences(tokenizer, max_length, description_list, feature)
        yield ([input_image, input_sequence], output_word)
```

just make the yeild to tuple from list.